# LWUIT Wrong size of scrollbar recalculate?

Tags: layout, java-me, nokia, lwuit

I'm using LWUIT on a Nokia Device.
The Form which is displayed contains several different `LayoutManagers()`, `Flow+Y_AXIS` and many Labels. Those get added in a Class which parses an XML file. This class gets returned and is displayed by another Class.

The scrollbar is sometimes "too short", meaning there's still text on the form which is cutoff, or hidden under the soft buttons.

Is there a function to have the layout recalculated?

I tried `form.getContentPane().layoutContainer();` and `form.invalidate(); form.revalidate();`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Revalidate is enough to layout, it is invoked implicitly when showing a form. If you are using the scrollbar in SVN should be pretty accurate for all lengths of data, if you have a compiling working test case where the scrollbar isn't accurately calculated you can use the LWUIT issue tracker ( http://java.net/jira/browse/LWUIT ) to submit a bug report and attach said test case.

Comment: Happened with svn last week, updating right now, but I guess nothing changed from then. I'll try to build a testcase which triggers the bug, as unfortunately I can't upload the code I'm working on.